# view.getId() not equals R.id.myBtn

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to determine which button was pressed and do something,
but can't find `R.id.myBtn's id`.
how can I do?

**Activity Code**

```
private int id

public void myCode(View view) {
    id = view.getId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.myBtn1:
            testTest();
            break;
        case R.id.myBtn2:
            testTest();
            break;
    }
}

private void testTest() {
    if(id == R.id.myBtn1){  <== it's not equals
        //something
    }else if(id == R.id.myBtn2){ <== it's not equals
        //something
    }
    //something same for two button
}
```

Comment: pas your id in your testTest(int id){  // compare here }

Answer (score 4):

You should do like this

1. Implement in your Activity the `View.OnClickListener`

   ```
   public class Activity implements View.OnClickListener { }
   ```
2. Register callbacks of the buttons to the `OnClickListener`

   ```
   Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   button1.setOnClickListener(this);
   button2.setOnClickListener(this);
   button3.setOnClickListener(this);
   ```
3. And in your `OnClick` method should look like this

   ```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       switch (view.getId()) {
           case R.id.button1:
               // button 1 is click
               break;
           case R.id.button2:
               // button 2 is click
               break;
           case R.id.button3:
               // button 3 is click
               break;
           default:
               break;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: think you,  and I want do some same things for all button and it have little different,how can I determine button N is click in other public void XXX(){}?

Comment: @vanessaHF please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the same method with the same parameters (none in your case):

```
private int id

public void myCode(View view) {
    id = view.getId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.myBtn1:
            testTest();//<---- executes testTest()
            break;
        case R.id.myBtn2:
            testTest();//<---- executes testTest()
            break;
    }
}

private void testTest() {
    if(id == R.id.myBtn1){  <== it's not equals
        //something
    }else if(id == R.id.myBtn2){ <== it's not equals
        //something
    }
    //something same for two button
}
```

Either remove the `testTest()` method and execute the button logic inside the `switch` or pass the id as a parameter to `testTest(int vid)` as the other comments suggested.

```
public void myCode(View view) {
    testTest(view.getId());
}

private void testTest(int viewId) {
    switch (viewId) {
        case R.id.myBtn1:
            //Action for R.id.myBtn1
            break;
        case R.id.myBtn2:
            //Action for R.id.myBtn2
            break;
    }
}
```